# What are the chances to spawn 4 baby horses in a row in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

so this is just something I was wondering. I was trying out my texture pack, and when I was trying to spawn in horses, I spawned in 4 baby horses in a row. What are the chances of this?

[image]

Here is what I searched, and found no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_Egg), the chance of spawning a baby horse is **20%**.

Calculating the chance of that occurring 4 times in a row:

```
0.2 * 0.2 * 0.2 * 0.2 = 0.0016 = 0.16%
```

As you can see, that's very unlikely.

However, there is another mechanic in Minecraft: When you use the Spawn Egg on a mob (in your case, the horse), you will **always** spawn a baby mob.
This would raise your chance back up to 20%. So not that unlikely.

Comment: Let's add right-clicking the spawn egg on an adult mob spawns the baby every time.